# msbuild - Is it possible to share items defined in a child project to its parent without using Import?

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-core, csproj

## Question

How do I get items defined in a child project to its parent without using the `<Import>` element?
The reason I want to avoid `<Import>` is because it also imports targets which execute at the parent project, which is not desired.

## Example

Say I have the following **`child.csproj`**:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <MyItem Include="some.file" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="MyChildPreBuild" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Message Text="MyChildPreBuild" Importance="high" />
        <Message Text="%(MyItem.FullPath)" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

And this is referenced by a **`parent.csproj`**:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <MyItem Include="some.other.file" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\child\child.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="MyPreBuild" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Message Text="MyPreBuild" Importance="high" />
        <Message Text="%(MyItem.FullPath)" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Building `parent.csproj`, I get the following build output message:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: child, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>child -> C:\Users\dan\test\child\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\child.dll
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: parent, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>parent -> C:\Users\dan\test\parent\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\parent.dll
2>C:\Users\dan\test\parent\some.other.file
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

As can be seen, only the `parent.csproj` `MyItem` items are printed.

Adding `<Import Project="..\child\child.csproj" />` to `parent.csproj` does print all of the `MyItem`s but the child's target is executed as well:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: child, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>child -> C:\Users\dan\test\child\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\child.dll
1>MyChildPreBuild
1>C:\Users\dan\test\child\some.file
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: parent, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>C:\Users\dan\test\child\child.csproj : warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Users\dan\test\parent\parent.csproj". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored.
2>C:\Users\dan\test\parent\parent.csproj : warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Users\dan\test\child\child.csproj". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored.
2>parent -> C:\Users\dan\test\parent\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\parent.dll
2>MyChildPreBuild
2>C:\Users\dan\test\parent\some.other.file
2>C:\Users\dan\test\parent\some.file
2>MyPreBuild
2>C:\Users\dan\test\parent\some.other.file
2>C:\Users\dan\test\parent\some.file
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `import` method you can add a condition to the child targets to only execute when that flag is not set. Then, in your parent, set the flag to a value.

Child

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <MyItem Include="some.file" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="MyChildPreBuild" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="'$(ParentProject}'==''">
        <Message Text="MyChildPreBuild" Importance="high" />
        <Message Text="%(MyItem.FullPath)" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

And then, in your parent project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <ParentProject>parent.csproj</ParentProject>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <MyItem Include="some.other.file" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Import Project="..\child\child.csproj" />

    <Target Name="MyPreBuild" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Message Text="MyPreBuild" Importance="high" />
        <Message Text="%(MyItem.FullPath)" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

This should prevent the child targets from being called when imported.